# pom.xml: run - edit configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Создал первый проект, добавил первую зависимость, но проект не build'ится. В чем проблема? Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кликни на Enable Auto-import в окошке в правом нижнем углу.